# Pandas to create a conditional column by selecting multiple columns in two different dataframes/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Problem: I have 2 data frames;

1. df1 has coil_id,sample_factor, seq. Each coil_id has 449 records (range 1-499) and has about 1000 unique coil_ids.
2. df2 has coil_id,sample, gauge. Each coil_id has 500 records approx (range 10-5000; can be less) and has same 1000 unique coil_ids as in df1.

df1:

```
+-------+-----------------
|coil_id|sample_factor|SEQ
+-------+-----------------
|E101634|10.4066      |  1
|E101634|20.8132      |  2
|E101634|31.2198      |  3 
|E101634|41.6264      |  4
|E101634|5220.033     |449
```

df2:

```
+-------+------+------+--
|coil_id|SAMPLE|GAUGE |
+-------+------+------+--
|E101634|    10|0.0565|
|E101634|    20|0.0569|
|E101634|    30|0.0567|
|E101634|    40|0.0561|
|E101634|  5000| 0.055|
```

I cannot join both tables due to different number of records. If i do so my sample values and gauge changes. So i should not join.
Next, i need to check whether **df1.sample_factor lies in between df2.sample and df2.sample+1** then perform a calculation on gauge.
 Example: ( if 10.4 lie in between 10 and 20 then **0.0565+(((0.0569-0.0565)/10)*(10.4-10))** ) basically Pro-rate the gauge.

I want to iterate each row from Sample_factor in df1, and check if it lies between sample[i] and sample[i+1] in df2. and then perform pro-rate on gauge and add the results to df1.

I tried this:

```
def new_gauge : for row in df1('sample_factor'):
    if df1['sample_factor'] > df2['sample'] and df1['sample_factor'] < df2['sample'] + 1:
        return df2['gauge']+(((df2['gauge']+1)-df2['gauge'])/10)*(df1['sample_factor']-df2['sample']))
df1['new_gauge'] = df1.apply(new_gauge)
```

I know its absolutely wrong in syntax, its just for an idea of what i want.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you:)

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: I think you asked this yesterday. I had a solution that I deleted because I wasn't entirely sure of your expected output. Can you add the expected output of the `'new_gauge'` to `df1` for each of the rows, just so I can verify my calculation is being done properly?

Comment: Thanks for replying back. I haven't tried your code yesterday, was about to try today but it was gone. Glad you responded. I added the screenshot of the output im expecting. 'new_gauge' is what ever the calculation would yield.

Comment: But can you actually calculate a few of those numbers for me? You're missing 1 closing parenthesis in the math, so it's difficult to know the correct order of operations

Comment: Done!! Please check. Thank you.

Comment: formula on excel =E2+(((E3-E2)/10)*(C3-D2)). But this is just a calculation without checking condition if Sample_factor is in between 2 samples.

Comment: formula of prorate also changed in the problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the starting sample data to match your expected output

`df1`

```
   coil_id  sample_factor  SEQ
0  E101634        10.4066    1
1  E101634        20.8132    2
2  E101634        31.2198    3
3  E101634        41.6264    4
4  E101634        52.0330    5
5  E101634        62.4396    6
6  E101634      5220.0330  449
```

`df2`

```
   coil_id  SAMPLE   GAUGE
0  E101634      10  0.0550
1  E101634      20  0.0568
2  E101634      30  0.0543
3  E101634      40  0.0531
4  E101634      50  0.0529
5  E101634      60  0.0519
```

---

The first step is to `merge_asof` to bring the sample factor to the sample which is the closest. Then calculate the `new_gauge` column for every row. However, we'll only actually assign a value if sample_factor falls in between the value of its current row and the next row AND the coil_id is the same for it and the next row.

```
import pandas as pd

merged = pd.merge_asof(df2.assign(SAMPLE = df2.SAMPLE.astype('float')).sort_values('SAMPLE'), 
                       df1.sort_values('sample_factor'),
                       by='coil_id',
                       left_on='SAMPLE',
                       right_on='sample_factor',
                       direction='forward')
print(merged)
#   coil_id  SAMPLE   GAUGE  sample_factor  SEQ
#0  E101634    10.0  0.0550        10.4066    1
#1  E101634    20.0  0.0568        20.8132    2
#2  E101634    30.0  0.0543        31.2198    3
#3  E101634    40.0  0.0531        41.6264    4
#4  E101634    50.0  0.0529        52.0330    5
#5  E101634    60.0  0.0519        62.4396    6

# Now perform your calculation:
new_gauge = (merged.GAUGE.shift(1) 
             + ((merged.GAUGE - merged.GAUGE.shift(1))/10 
                 * (merged.sample_factor - merged.SAMPLE.shift(1))))

# Assign it only where it makes sense
# Assumes df2 was sorted on ['coil_id',  'SAMPLE']
mask = (merged.sample_factor.between(merged.SAMPLE, merged.SAMPLE.shift(-1)) 
        & (merged.coil_id == merged.coil_id.shift(-1)))

merged.loc[mask, 'new_gauge'] = new_gauge[mask]
```

#### Output: `merged`

```
   coil_id  SAMPLE   GAUGE  sample_factor  SEQ  new_gauge
0  E101634    10.0  0.0550        10.4066    1        NaN
1  E101634    20.0  0.0568        20.8132    2   0.056946
2  E101634    30.0  0.0543        31.2198    3   0.053995
3  E101634    40.0  0.0531        41.6264    4   0.052905
4  E101634    50.0  0.0529        52.0330    5   0.052859
5  E101634    60.0  0.0519        62.4396    6        NaN
```

In this case, we didn't assign the final row because there was no Sample > 60 in the subset you provided.

Comment: Thanks alot. I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: @Abhinavneni Glad it helped! `merge_asof` is one of the lesser used pandas methods, but it really shines for calculations like this. Though there's a lot of pre-processing to get it to work (sorting, and making sure the merge keys are the same type. It's shocking that it cant merge `int` and `float` columns.¯.